Movie about someone running for (Vice?) President, fishing, a car-accident ending with a drowning, an investigation, woman VP?
I'm looking for an American movie, probably from the 1990s.
It starts with a car with a woman driving fast towards a bridge.  Nearby, a politician (senator or congressman?) and a reporter (or something) are fishing.  The car misses the bridge and goes into the water.  The politician tries to save the drowning woman, but eventually fails.  The politician later runs for President or Vice President.  I think also a woman is running for the same position, but she meets lots of opposition.  The sitting President takes some interest in this race.
Meanwhile, we see a woman doing "discreet inquiries" about one of the candidates - probably the woman...
Towards the end of the movie, another congressman - possibly representing a group of congressmen - meets with the President to convince him to support "the hero" rather than the woman.  When the President asks if he would stake his reputation on the "hero" congressman being suited, he replies that he does.

 The President then reveals that he's been making enquirers (the woman investigator) that proves the "hero" congressman had actually paid the drowned woman, and that the plan was for the congressman to save her on camera to boost his chances of winning.  The President then demands the congressman's support for the woman candidate... which he gets.  And she wins.

Does this sounds familiar?

This is the 2000 film, The Contender, starring Joan Allen as the potential vice president.The plot unfolds pretty much as you described, including the opening scene of a woman driving off a bridge. (The song playing was a cover of Johnny Cash's "Ring of Fire", I distinctly remember.) 
After his Vice-president suddenly dies, the President (Jeff Bridges) who is near the end of his final term, decides to leave a legacy by selecting a woman to fill the position. Enter a Senator (Joan Allen), who has shifted from the Republican Party to the Democratic. Initially appearing to be the perfect candidate, an allegation suddenly appears that she had been involved in a sexual orgy as a 19 year old in college. The confirmation committee chairman (Gary Oldman), a Republican, leaks the information to the press, while using the press discussion as a forum to bring it into the hearings. The chairman desires to get a Governor (William Petersen) into the office. The Governor had become a national hero when he attempted to rescue a young woman from a car that crashed from a bridge into deep water near where the Governor had been fishing. 
